# Help proving that there exists $a^i\equiv a^j (mod \space n)$ with $i\ne j$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I have to prove the following theorem for my course on Number Theory,

> Let $a$ and $n$ be natural numbers. Then there exist natural numbers $i$ and $j$, with $i\ne j$, such that $a^i\equiv a^j (mod \space n)$ with $i\ne j$

I have absolutely no idea how to prove this. Please note that I have not learned Fermat's Little Theorem yet and cannot use it in the proof. Could I receive some generous help and hints please?

Comment: Pigeonhole principle.

Comment: Where is the b? I think you need to fix the notation.

Comment: Hint: How many distinct residues are there, mod $n$? Reduced mod $n$, can
$$
a,a^2,a^3,...,a^{n+1}
$$
all be distinct?

Comment: Re-read the comment of Kenta S.  The elements of the congruency class, $\pmod{n}$ are $\{0,1,2,\cdots, [n-1]\}.$

Comment: When I see congruency classes I think of the property that there exists a unique integer $t$ in the set $\{0,1,2,\cdots, [n-1]\}$ such that $a \equiv t (mod \space n)$ holds...I don't know where to go from here. I'm really really bad at this sort of math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every integer number $m$ can be written uniquely in the form $m = qn + r$, where $0 \leq r < n$. So, one can group together all the integer numbers with the same residue $r$ after division by $n$. Then, we get the set $[0]=\{kn:k\in \mathbb{Z}\}, \space [1]=\{kn+1:k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$, ... , $[n-1]=\{kn + (n-1):k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Consider the set $A = \{a^i:i=0,\dots,n\}$. This set has cardinality $n+1$.

But there are only $n$ residue classes: $[0],[1],...,[n-1]$.

Then, by the pigeonhole principle, we conclude that there are two elements in this set $A$, say $a^i,a^j$, that belong to the same class $[b]$. In other words, there exist $i,j=0,\dots,n$, $i\neq j$, such that $a^i\equiv_n b \equiv_n a^j$.

Comment: So we have a set from $0$ to $n$ that represents all the possible exponents of $a^i$ and what you're saying is that we can only choose one integer each from this set to attach to $a^i$ and $a^j$. Is this correct? Going from that, how does this conclude that $a^i\equiv a^j (mod \space n)$ holds true?

Comment: @BobbyB I am saying that there are **n** classes of residues: [0], [1], ... , [n-1]. And this set has **n+1** elements. So, if one attaches to each $a^i$ the respective residue class, then one has to repeat at least one residue class. It's impossible two put n+1 balls in n boxes without putting at least two balls in some box.

Comment: I think I'm fundamentally misunderstanding what this theorem is actually stating and this is why I'm so confused. What I believe this theorem to be stating is that we can take the congruence of the form $a\equiv a (mod \space n)$ and raise each $a$ to different exponents such that $a^i\equiv a^j (mod \space n)$ holds where $i\ne j$. How do I connect this idea to the logic of proof?

Comment: @BobbyB Well... That's the beauty of being a mathematician! :D To understand and to prove are frequently different things, and to do both is the work of the mathematician. Now, answering your doubt. In fact, this result we are trying to prove doesn't tell the all story (that is why you made a secon question about $a^k \equiv 1$, and then you will learn Fermat's Little Theorem, which tells much more of what really is going one when you take powers a see the residue class mod $n$

Comment: @BobbyB That being said, to understand this result, imagine you have a lot of balls, say $2021n$, each with a different number $a^i$. And imagine you have $n$ boxes, each numbered from $1$ to $n$, or from $0$ to $n-1$, or numbered with your favorite representative of each class of residues mod $n$. Now, when you try to organize all those balls inside the respective boxes, you will necessarily have repetitions in at least one of the boxes. That is what this result is saying

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand. When you see $a^i\equiv a^j (mod \space n)$, how do you know this represents an application of the Pigeonhole Theorem?

Comment: @BobbyB I've edit the answer. I hope it is more helpfull now.