# Help proving there exists a natural number $k$ such that $a^k\equiv 1 (mod \space n)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I need to prove the following theorem for my Number Theory class,

> Let $a$ and $n$ be natural numbers with $gcd(a,n)=1$. Then there exists a natural number $k$ such that $a^k\equiv 1 (mod \space n)$

I'm immensely awful at proofing so I have absolutely no idea how to prove this theorem. I haven't learned Fermat's Little Theorem yet so I can't use it in the proof either (if it's even applicable). But I do know how we define a residue systems modulo $n$, if that's useful. Could I please receive some guidance?

Comment: Do you know Bezout's lemma?

Comment: If this is the lemma you are referring to, then yes I do know it well. https://brilliant.org/wiki/bezouts-identity/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $n$ numbers $a^1,...,a^n$.

Because $\gcd(a,n)=1$ then $a^i \not \equiv 0 \pmod n $ for all $i=1,...,n$. Hence there are $n-1$ possible values from $1$ to $n-1$ for $n$ numbers $a^1,...,a^n$. According to the Pigeonhole principle, there exists $i,j \in \{1,...,n\}$ such that $i \ne j$ and
$$a^j \equiv a^i \pmod n\implies a^i(a^{j-i}-1) \equiv0 \pmod n \implies a^{j-i} \equiv 1 \pmod n$$

Let's take $k = j-i$, then $a^{k} \equiv 1 \pmod n$

Comment: I'm confused from the first line...how do you know that a greatest common divisor of 1 between $a$ and $n$ leads to $a^i \not \equiv 0 \pmod n$?

Comment: @BobbyB Because if there exists $i$ such that $a^i \equiv 0 \bmod n$, then $n|a$ or $\gcd(a,n)  = n>1$.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. So going from that, you're saying because $a^i \not \equiv 0 \pmod n$ is true then then there must exist an unique integer $a^j$ in the set ${a^1,...,a^n}$ that satisfies $a^i\equiv a^j (mod \space n)$? I do believe this works off the theorem I posted here (that I also can't understand): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4055739/help-proving-that-there-exists-ai-equiv-aj-mod-space-n-with-i-ne-j?noredirect=1#comment8377993_4055739

Comment: @BobbyB Yes, According to the pigeonhole principe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle , if you have $n$ pigeons ($a^i$) but $n-1$ pigeonholes ($1,2,...,(n-1)$) then of couse, there exists at least 2 pigeons in the same pigeonhole.

Answer (score 1):

I refer to you're other question [Help proving that there exists $a^i\equiv a^j (mod \space n)$ with $i\ne j$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4055739/help-proving-that-there-exists-ai-equiv-aj-mod-space-n-with-i-ne-j)

There are $0\leq i<j$ such that $a^i\equiv_n a^j \equiv_n a^{j-i} a^i$.

On the other hand, $a^i$ and $n$ are coprime, so there are $x,y$ such that $a^i x + n y = 1$. Looking to the residues mod $n$, we get $a^i x \equiv_n 1$.

Therefore, $1 \equiv_ n a^i x \equiv_n a^j x \equiv_n a^{j-1} a^i x \equiv_n a^{j-i}$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the powers $a^1, a^2, a^3,\dots$.  They can't all be different, because there are only finitely many residue classes, so there exist $0<j<k$ with $a^j=a^k$.

Can you take it from here?

Hmmm.  I guess I'm assuming you've learned about the extended Euclidean algorithm, or Bezout's theorem.

Comment: What do you mean by "they can't all be different"? If we're choosing different possible exponents for $a^i$ for a finite set, won't all powers be different?

Comment: I am familiar with the extended Euclidean algorithm but I can't see how to apply it to your opening logic.

Comment: @BobbyB All the exponents will be different of course, but the results can't all be different.  There are only $n$ residue classes modulo $n$, so we can't have infinitely many distinct powers.  As to your second question, what do you conclude from $a^j=a^k$?

Comment: By $a^j=a^k$ do you mean $a^j \equiv a^k \pmod n$? I don't know what to conclude from this. Am I supposed to put it into the extended Euclidean algothim as $a^jx+a^ky=gcd(a^j,a^k)$? But that seems wrong as I have no idea how to lead off that...

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.  If $a^j\equiv a^k\pmod{n}$ the $1\equiv a^{k-j}\pmod{n}$  We can multiply both sides by $a^{-j}$ because by the extended Euclidean algorithm, we know that $a$ has a multiplicative in verse modulo $n$.